# Modifying the 'className' property is extremely slow in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

On my website, I dynamically modify the javascript 'className' property of a DIV. However this is an extrememly expensive operation, as the DIV contains a lot of child nodes. Sometimes it takes up to 1.5secs.

Is there a way of speeding up this operation? Like, hiding the content, performing the operation, then showing the content again?

**Update:**

Some additional information.

The actual code:

```
$("#myDiv").tabs();
```

It is located witin the .ready() handler. See
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

This is the expensive call. I tracked it further down to the **className** property, which consumes all that processing time.

The DIV contains a big sharepoint datagrid, see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.renderashtml.aspx
The code is run on Sharepoint, tested on WinXP + IE7.

So I wonder if we can disable the layout refreshing while manipulating the DOM or something like that. Are there any tricks?

Comment: What's the code look like that you're currently using to do the modification?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using, and the HTML (or a sample of it) that is being modified?

Comment: Have you tried elem.setAttribute("class", 'newclassname')?

Comment: What CSS properties change when you change the class? When you say a lot, what range are we talking about? 10s-100s? Could you show us the jquery code you use to change the class? Changing the className of a div is usually inmediate, so your problem comes because of the context, but we don't know anything about it.

Comment: I'm confused. The number of child nodes of the `div` should have no effect on changing the class of the `div` itself. Is it your intention to chance the class of the children too?

Comment: @patrick That's not true at all - if the container class drives a whole bunch of CSS selectors, and the content layout must be recomputed when the class name changes, then there's potentially a tremendous amount of work that poor addled IE7 has to carry out.

Comment: @Pointy - I see your point (no pun intended), but then wouldn't the same lag manifest itself when the page loads as well? (I guess maybe it does in this case.)

Comment: Can you post a demo- HTML file? It would be interesting how this perform in FF / chrome. Don't know if something like http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/browserSpeed.html might be worth a look at.

Comment: Update: I added some information on the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

Try making sure that the CSS selectors that affect elements contained within the container whose class name is changing only use the container class when they really have to. Obviously, when you're driving layout with the container class, there are probably a lot of things affected, but sometimes it's easy to drop in `div.whatever td.currency` when really all you need is `td.currency` (just a made-up example).

The IE layout engine is really fast for some things, but I've found that heavy use of this sort of layout technique (which is, I believe, a very good practice in general) can tax the browser a lot.  Thankfully, IE8 is a lot better at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved ~50% performance improvment when switching tabs by removing the two tabs to switch from their parent before changing the `className` property. For implementation details, see https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom